# Align the column with the display:table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to render a `HTML table` layout with the `css` properties :

```
display:table, table-row, table-cell...
```

Here is what I want to get :

```
+---------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------+
| my li         |            a content in a li          | another content |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------+
| my li         | a longer content that expend the cell | another content |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------+
| my li         |        foo bar foo bar in a li        |    a content    |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

This is what I got:

```
+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| my li         | a content in a li | another content |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------+
| my li         | a longer content that expend the cell | another content |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------+
| my li         | foo bar foo bar in a li |    a content in li    |
+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Is there a way to *align* the *columns* without setting the `width` explicitly ?

Here is the code:

```
#container{
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
#container ul {
  display: table-row;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}
#container ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
#container ul li:first-child  {
  text-align: left;
}


<div id="container">
<ul><li>my li</li><li>a content in a li</li><li>another content</li></ul>
<ul><li>my li</li><li>a longer content that expend the cell</li><li>another content</li></ul>
<ul><li>my li</li><li>foo bar foo bar in a li</li><li>a content in li</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks ok to me http://jsfiddle.net/Nj7QN/

Comment: In what browser this is not working ? For me it is ok with Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I checked the code and it's working for me too if I have only the snippet that I wrote above. 
In my App, it wasn't displayed correctly because of a `float:left` declared for all `li{...}`... I corrected it with a

```
#container ul li{
... 
float: none;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `table-layout: fixed;` to your `#container` selector:

```css
#container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    ...
}
```

From [MDN's notes on `table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout):

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.